# How can I get the element of the current day selected in the calendar of Jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I am trying to get the component of the selected element in the Jquery UI calendar, but with the datepicker - onselect, it selects the day that is previously marked and not the one that I am selecting. this is my code.

```
$('#eventCalendar').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            //dateFormat: 'd M yy',
            inline: true,
            minDate: 0,
            //minDate: '10-01-01',
            //minDate: '1 Jan 2010',
            onSelect: function (date) {
                printVcInfo(date);
                console.log("hello" + $(".ui-state-active").first().text());
            }
        });
```

The console shows the previous day that was selected and any action performed is done on the previous day. Some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the change date event. On select, the css class, has not been applied yet.

```
$('#eventCalendar').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            //dateFormat: 'd M yy',
            inline: true,
            minDate: 0,
            //minDate: '10-01-01',
            //minDate: '1 Jan 2010'
       }}.bind('dateSelected', function(e, selectedDate, $td) {
        Console.log(selectedDate);
    });
```

Comment: It does not work, the bind never enters. I do not know why I deleted the complete code and I put it as you copied it, and I also fixed the keys and neither.